# Insertion sort using pointer to an array

Tags: c++, sorting

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void insertion(int*, int);
int main() {
    int a[6] = {9, 5, 3, 7, 5, 6};
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)    
        cout << a[i] << " ";

    insertion(&a[0], 6);
    cout << "now insertion sort \n";
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
        cout << a[x] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
void insertion(int* l, int m) {    
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {    
        while (*(l + i) > *(l + 1 + i) && (i > 0)) {
            temp = *(l + i);
            *(l + i + 1) = *(l + i);
            *(l + i) = temp;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the function sorting?
The output that I'm getting is: `9 5 5 7 7 7`

What other details should I add (this is my first doubt in stackoverflow)?

Comment: Tip:  use std::swap instead of temp when swapping values.

Comment: There also doesn't really seem to be any good reason to be using direct pointer arithmetic rather than simple indexing. Replacing ``*(l+i+1)`` with simply ``l[i+1]`` is a lot more readable/robust to changes in the size of ``l``'s datatype.

Comment: You can also replace ``&a[0]`` with simply ``a``, they are equivalent in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic isn't really correct for an insertion sort. In fact, what you have right now is much closer to a bubble sort (though it's obviously not quite right for that either).

For an insertion sort, the logic goes something like this (assuming 0-based indexing):

```
for i = 1 to array_length
    if array[i] < array[i-1]
        temp = array[i]
        for j = i downto 1 && temp < array[j-1]
            array[j] = array[j-1]
        array[j-1] = temp
    endif
```

So the basic idea here is that for each element, we search backwards through the array to find the right place to put that element. As we do so, we shift elements upwards by one spot, so when we got to the right spot, we have a place to put it.

Note, in particular, that this doesn't contain any swap-like code anywhere. We don't normally plan on swapping adjacent elements as you've done. It can/will happen when/if an element happens to be out of place by exactly one position, but it's pretty much incidental when it does.

Comment: thanks for the help. I wanted to do it using pointers and I did it
again Thanks!!